# Securing my REST API from anonymous calls

Tags: java, android, rest

I have made REST API for my Android Application. But I want to secure it from any anonymous access. Only my Android app should be able to access it. How can I do it.  I thought of an API token which I will hash and send it to my REST Server with every request from my Android app. But its not secure as network sniffers can easily find hashed token and can send it to my REST Server. Is there any full proof way from which I can secure my REST API

Comment: Have you considered using HTTPS?

Comment: https needs certificates and all. I don't have all of that

Comment: It does but your certificates need not always be signed. You can generate your own certificates. How does Android handle unsigned certificates? Does it hinder user experience?

Comment: Considered laugh? Pretty much the standard for large restful APIs (fob,twitter,etc) http://oauth.net

Answer (score 0):

As someone mentioned in the comment section, you can consider HTTPS. If you host your webservice say for instace on [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services), you can have a two way secure line. The application gets the public keys in a certificate, and the webserver demands a client certificate back. An introduction to the topic: [how to set up ssl on iis](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis). For the certificate generation I would highly recommend using [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/).

On the other hand, you can take a look at Google's [App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/), I've looked through this [tutorial](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/05/Authenticating-against-App-Engine-from-an-Android-app), which seems nice.

Good luck!